# What does the `-?` (dash question) and `-readonly` (dash readonly) syntax mean in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, syntax, option-type, access-modifiers

I am new to TypeScript and saw the following in the @types/prop-types package. What does `-?` mean in `[K in keyof T]-?`?

```js
export type ValidationMap<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?: Validator<T[K]> };
```

Similarly, what does `-readonly [K in keyof T]?` mean in [immer](https://github.com/immerjs/immer/blob/75e004db1374e059773047e786d6d01ee1e90a0f/src/types/types-external.ts#L33)?

```js
export type WritableDraft<T> = {-readonly [K in keyof T]: Draft<T[K]>}
```

I tried my best to google that, but failed.

Thank you.

---

*Extra keywords: hyphen, minus, grammar*

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a newbie question. You're looking inside a package. Why do you undervalue yourself?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Homomorphic mapped types copy the optionality of the original type field to the mapped type field. The `-?` is the syntax used to explicitly remove any optional modifier from the resulting mapped type.

Similarly, `-readonly` removes the *"readonlyness"*.

You can read more details [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21919).

Comment: @Park Welcome to SO! If this answer is correct, you should make it the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Comment: I've been looking for a way of doing this for so long!

Comment: As of late 2020, the Handbook still doesn't document this syntax, except [this blurb in the 2.8 release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#improved-control-over-mapped-type-modifiers).  There's an [open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-Website/issues/595) to get the docs in the right place.

Comment: @Coderer the new docs are definitely improved, but there is also lots of room for improvement 

Comment: Since you're here, did you happen to see [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64449138/26286)?  That's what led me to this one.